# Fortran: Initialization of allocatable array with another array

Tags: fortran, lazy-initialization, allocatable-array

I read a Fortran code :

```
  program t
    real :: x(5)  =[1.,-2.,3.,-4.,5.]
    real,allocatable :: y(:)
    y = x
    ...
```

For me the normal way is
`allocate(y,source=x)`

I'm surprised that it works, both compile with ifort or gfortran

Is there something new in the fortran standards that I'm not aware of?

Comment: It's a little surprising you would call `allocate(y,source=x)` the normal way, as `y=x` has worked this way for as long as sourced allocation has existed in Fortran. One notable difference between the two ways is that `y` must not be allocated for the allocate statement, but can for the assignment (not initialization).

Comment: Another difference being around assignment involving polymorphic variables (not the case in this example), but could be a good alternative question.

Comment: Another difference you can check for error with `allocate`. What good it will do you, damn lazy allocation ...

Comment: And since Fortran 2008: `allocate(a,b,c,source=x)` instead of `a=x; b=x; c=x`.